# how to trigger a workflow using a button click in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a list with manager and subordinate Email as lookup and text data type respectively .

The requirement is the manager can login and click a button which trigger an email to the subordinate.
Is there any way to click a button which trigger an email to all of the subordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Since the subordinates are a lookup on the click event get all the subordinates email and then use the SPUtility.SendEmail API to send the email.

```
 $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': "you@company.com",
    'To': { 'results': to},       
    'CC': { 'results': cc},       
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
                  }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(err) {

        }
    });
```

To send email to multiple user just append all the email to the to variable comma separated.

to="user1@company.com,user2@company.com"

Comment: I am sorry but subordinates are not lookup it is text. The manager field however is.

Comment: Even if it is a text you can resolve the users(Web.Ensureuser())  and get the emails right?